# Clustering by date (by distance) in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, cluster-analysis

I have a huge journal with actions done by users (like, for example, moderating contents).
I would like to find the 'mass' actions, meaning the actions that are too dense (the user probably made those actions without thinking it too much :) ).

That would translate to clustering the actions by date (in a linear space), and to marking the clusters that are too dense.

I am no expert in clustering algorithms and methods, but I think the [k-means clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) would not do the trick, since I don't know the number of clusters.
Also, ideally, I would also like to 'fine tune' the algorithm.

What would you advice?

P.S. Here are some resources that I found (in Ruby):

- [hierclust](https://github.com/Empact/hierclust) - a simple hierarchical clustering library for spatial data
- [AI4R](http://ai4r.rubyforge.org/) - library that implements some clustering algorithms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at density based clustering. E.g. [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) and OPTICS.

This sounds like exactly what you want.

Answer (score 4):

K-means would probably do a good job as long as you're interested in an *a priori* known number of clusters. Since you don't you might consider reading about the [LBG algorithm](http://www.data-compression.com/vq.html#lbg), which is based on k-means and is used in data compression for vector quantisation. It's basically iterative k-means which splits centroids after they converge and keeps splitting until you achieve an acceptable number of clusters.

On the other hand, since your data is one-dimensional, you could do something completely different.

Assume that you've got actions which took place at 5 points in time: (8, 11, 15, 16, 17). Let's plot a Gaussian for each of these actions with μ equal to the time and σ = 3.

[image]

Now let's see how a sum of values of these Gaussians looks like.

[image]

It shows a density of actions with a peak around 16.

Based on this observation I propose a following simple algorithm.

1. Create a vector of zeroes for the time range of interest.
2. For each action calculate the Gaussian and add it to the vector.
3. Scan the vector looking for values which are greater than the maximum value in the vector multiplied by α.

Note that for each action only a small section of the vector needs updates because values of a Gaussian converge to zero very quickly.

You can tune the algorithm by adjusting values of

1. α ∈ [0,1], which indicates how significant a peak of activity has to be to be noted,
2. σ, which affects the distance of actions which are considered close to each other, and
3. time periods per vector's element (minutes, seconds, etc.).

Notice that the algorithm is linear with regard to the number of actions. Moreover, it shouldn't be difficult to parallelise: split your data across multiple processes summing Gaussians and then sum generated vectors.